# I have 20 odd source file from where I am collating data into one file, facing issue in pulling the source file name also as identifier

Tags: excel, vba

My Code so far does paste the selected data from all the source files, however I also need the source file name to recognize which data belongs to which source file and this name should occur beside the column where data is pasted each time.

```
Sub OpenFilesCopyPasteVI()

Dim SFile As Workbook
Dim SFname As Worksheet
Dim SFname2 As Worksheet
Dim SFlname As String
Dim I As Long
Dim DFile As Workbook
Dim Acellrng As String

Pth = "C:\XYZ\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set SFile = ThisWorkbook
Set SFname = SFile.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set SFname2 = SFile.Worksheets("Sheet3")
numrows = SFname.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For I = 1 To numrows

SFlname = SFname.Range("A" & I).Value

If SFname.Range("A" & I).Value <> "" Then

Workbooks.Open Pth & SFlname

Set DFile = Workbooks(SFlname)
 
Cells.Find(What:="ABC", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Activate

Acellrng = ActiveCell.Address

Range(Acellrng).Select

ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=SFile.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(SFile.Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

DFile.Close

**'I need help to automate this part where I need the source file name in the last column each time beside the data pasted**
SFname2.Range("K3", "K18").Value = SFlname

End If

Next I

MsgBox "job done"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You already have the file name (in SFname) because you need it to open the file from which you extract data.

Comment: I have the file but how do I copy it automatically each time data is pasted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub OpenFilesCopyPasteVI()
    Const PTH As String = "C:\XYZ\" 'use const for fixed values
    
    Dim SFile As Workbook, SFname As Worksheet, SFname2 As Worksheet
    Dim SFlname As String, I As Long, DFile As Workbook
    Dim Acellrng As Range, ws As Worksheet, rngDest As Range, rngCopy As Range
    
    Set SFile = ThisWorkbook
    Set SFname = SFile.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set SFname2 = SFile.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For I = 1 To SFname.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        SFlname = SFname.Range("A" & I).Value
        If Len(SFlname) > 0 Then

            Set DFile = Workbooks.Open(PTH & SFlname)
            Set ws = DFile.Sheets(1) 'or other specifc sheet
            Set Acellrng = ws.Cells.Find(What:="ABC", _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
            
            If Not Acellrng Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopy = ws.Range(Acellrng, Acellrng.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
                Set rngDest = SFname2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                rngCopy.Copy rngDest
                'populate the file name in Column K next to the copied data
                rngDest.EntireRow.Columns("K").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = SFlname
            End If
            DFile.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    Next I
    
    MsgBox "job done"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim - the code works exactly as I wanted.

Comment: If the code works for you then please accept the answer by clicking the check next to it - that helps others coming along later to know your question has a working answer.